# 3 dimensional arraylist argumets are not applicable

Tags: java, arraylist

I am trying to make a program in Java about the Tabulation method. For those unfamiliar, one of the steps in Tabulation method is to group binaries with the same number of 1's digits. So we put the group with the same number of 1's digit in a arraylist. So if we have five different groups (1st group containing no 1's digits, 2nd group containing one 1's digits, and so on), we store them in another arraylist. Thus an arraylist of an arraylist.

In the Tabulation method, we compare the elements from each group with the elements from the proceeding group. Each time we find a similar element from the next group (exactly one digit that differs), then we put them in a new list. This list is again grouped from the number of 1's digit. Thus, we have an arraylist of an arraylist of an arraylist.

What I have here is a part of my code:

```
allTables.add(new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>().set(count, new ArrayList<String>().add(mintermBinaries[i])));
```

allTables is just an arraylist of an arraylist of an arraylist. The integer count determines the number of 1's digit a binary has and sets it in that index, and finally mintermBinaries[i], is the ith index of the array that contains all binaries in ascending order. The whole code is within a for loop.

The problem is it won't compile because according to Eclipse, the arguments are not applicable. I don't know why.

After thinking about this a lot, I'm not sure if a three dimensional array is even a good thing to do. Can anyone help? What is a better way to solve this?

Comment: `List.add()` returns boolean, but you try to treat result as `List`.

Answer (score 2):

```
new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>().set(
    count, 
    new ArrayList<String>().add(mintermBinaries[i]))
```

The second argument of `set()`, which is supposed to be an `ArrayList<String>` (since you're calling it on an `ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>`), is the expression

```
new ArrayList<String>().add(mintermBinaries[i])
```

The type of this expression is the type of the value returned by the method `add()`. And `add()` returns a boolean. And a boolean is not an `ArrayList<String>`.

Don't try to write all your code in a single line. Replace that with

```
List<ArrayList<String>> listOfLists = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
ArrayList<String> innerList = new ArrayList<String>();
innerList.add(mintermBinaries[i]);
listOfLists.set(count, innerList);
```

Comment: `listOfLists.set()` will throw as it is empty

Comment: @SashaSalauyou yes, but that's a different matter.

Answer (score 0):

As returninig result of `List#add()` and `List#set()` are different from what you expect, to use such one-liners, you need additional helper methods:

```
// Appends an item to the end of the list.
// Instead of `boolean`, returns modified list itself
static <T> List<T> add(List<T> list, T item) {
    list.add(item);
    return list;
}

// Sets an item to arbitrary position in `List`, expanding if needed.
// Instead of replaced item, returns modified list itself
static <T> List<T> set(List<T> list, int index, T item) {
    if (list.size() <= index) {
        for (int i = list.size(); i <= index; i++)
            list.add(null);
    }
    list.set(index, item);
    return list;
}
```

then you can write your code in one line:

```
add(allTables, set(new ArrayList<List<String>>(), count, add(new ArrayList<String>(), mintermBinaries[i])));
```

Although this is not very elegant and may be even confusing in your particular case (I'd also prefer to call `List.add()` and `.set()` sequentially), such approach may happen more clean and efficient in some situations.